# What about make site icon better for browser dark mode?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design, dark-mode

I just found some icons of Stack Exchange Network have problems in dark mode as in example https://cardano.meta.stackexchange.com/. have color problems. see image below.

[image: Very Dark Color]

So what about changing the Color. I asked this Question in [Cardano Meta](https://cardano.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/what-about-better-icon-more-releated-to-https-cardano-org). But Nike Dattani has saied the image is useless because it is Unicode Character

> I don't think that will be entertained because unless `it's a unicode character`. Sites don't get custom designs unless there's a sponsor, or the site becomes very mature (usually takes several years: Etherium.SE and Bitcoin.SE do not even have custom designs yet!).

So what is the solution here or we could just skip that and move forward ..

**Notice :** I mean All sites that face same problem in Dark Mode which Cardano Meta one of them.

Thanks All.

Comment: Are you asking us to make *all* site icons readable in dark mode browsers or just the one? If it's just the one, this question needs to stay on Cardano.

Comment: @Catija Actually All Stack Exchange Sites that have same problem (e.g Cardano)

Comment: Do most sites consider this? Is it common for sites to have icons that are different for both light and dark browsers? I'm not sure we even have a way to do this.

Comment: @Catija Me too not sure but I just actually also scope on Cardano Meta and any other site that have same problem in (Normal & Meta)

Comment: Just wanted to clarify that the fix we shipped here is for when the favicons show _within_ Stack Overflow, like in the hot network questions, or the communities in your profile. There currently isn't a bulletproof way to swap favicons in the browser tab for dark mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When this community added a favicon, it looks like we didn't get the dark mode version of the icon right. You can see this when comparing Cardono to others in our [sprite sheet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/Content/Img/favicons-sprite16-dark.png). The black should actually be a slightly lighter gray.

This will go out in the next build.